# Change fluentd config in GKE to move from Stackdriver to ELK

Tags: elastic-stack, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

When running a cluster on GKE, the VM image used to build the cluster comes with a fluentd-gcp.yaml file in

/etc/kubernetes/manifests

Consequently this launches one pod fluentd per node on the cluster.
This fluentd pod collects all container logs and forward them to stackdriver based on [this configuration](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp/fluentd-gcp-image/fluent.conf)

Now I'd like to use [the ELK version instead](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch). 
How can I do that in GKE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first disable the built in cluster logging (`gcloud container clusters create --no-enable-cloud-logging ...`) in your cluster. Then you can run the fluentd image of your choice on all nodes using a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/daemons/).

There isn't a way to change the logging configuration on a running cluster, so unfortunately you'll need to create a new cluster without the gcp fluentd logger running.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there no way to work around this without a complete cluster migration? I haven't done a migration yet but this seem like a delicate operation, especially for database. 

Where is stored the information that each VM of the cluster should have this manifest file in place with the fluentd logging to stackdriver, can't this be edited and changed?

Comment: You can modify the instance template and recreate nodes in your existing cluster, but changing the template is fragile and won't persist across node upgrades.